# Does HashMap uses hashCode-equals methods of the HashMap or object?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I am confused regarding to the internal working of HashMap and as far as I understood, HashMap uses hashCode() and equals() methods of the given object that is stored in map (that's why the implementation of these methods are so important). On the other hand, the sources that I followed explains that as if HashMap uses its internal hashCode-equals methods to compare key values. Which one is right? Could you pls clarify me? I know the scenario of put / remove, but just need the place of the hashCode-equals methods. Are they in HashMap or Object?

Comment: `HashMap` uses the `hashCode()` and `equals()` of the object being placed within it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. In this case there is not any hashCode() or equals() method in the HashMap,  right?

Comment: "In this case there is not any hashCode() or equals() method in the HashMap, right?" - There _is_ a `hashCode` method and an `equals` method in `HashMap`.  One consequence of that is that a `HashMap` could be used as a key in another map.

Comment: All objects have a `hashCode` and `equals` method that's inherited from the base `Object` class.  However, for the purposes of USING a `HashMap` it's irrelevant.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Your last comment is perfectly clarified me and that was exactly the point causing to be confused. **Your comment is the answer of the question**. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jonathan "Your comment is the answer of the question" - Awesome!  I am glad you got what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In `HashMap`, Keys are hashed and compared, not the values. So, if you want to use your own  objects as a Key, you need to implement hashCode and equals methods. e.g. You may want to store Student and corresponding Marksheet in a `HashMap` then for using Student objects as Key, override hashCode and equals method in that class.

If you just want to use String as key, then `HashMap` would call `hashCode` and `equals` method of String class

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. In this case there is not any hashCode() or equals() method in the HashMap, right?

Comment: `HashMap` calls `hashCode` method of the Key not it's own

Answer (score 1):

It uses it on the `Object` to facilitate key lookup.  Here is an example.
Imagine you had `1000` files of individuals in a box and you had the `ID number` of one you had to find.  So you need to go thru the box and search thru 1000 files to find the correct one.

Now imagine that you had two boxes. And all the even id's were in one box marked even and all the odd ones in a box marked odd.  By looking at the ID you can pick the proper box (even or odd).   So statistically you would only have to search thru about 500 files.

- So the `hashCode` generates `"boxes"` based on the key.
- And the search for the exact `key` within a box uses `equals`.

In my example, `hashCode()` could return `0` or `1` via something like the following:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id % 2; // returns 0 or 1 for even or odd box
}
```

Ideally a `hashCode` that generates many boxes (within reason) is best as the boxes become smaller (holds fewer objects).  And a `hashCode` of a fixed value will work but it reduces the  map to a single `box` with no benefit of improved performance.